# Скрипт который отслеживает изменения свободного \ занятого дискового пространства

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

Нужно чтобы скрипт запускался каждые 7-10 сек до тех пор, пока не будет выключен, и выдавал результат, изменений который произошли на диске.
Я это вижу так, но тут выводится просто результат, а не отслуживаются изменения.

```
while(true) do
       clear
       df -h | sort -rn
       sleep 7
done
```

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, но комментарий по поводу текущего использования: это обычно делается в виде `watch -n 7 "df -h | sort -rn"`

Comment: А то, что вы хотите... В вашем цикле выдавайте результат в какой-нибудь файл newfile, выводите `diff oldfile newfile`, потом переименовывайте newfile в oldfile и так по кругу.

Comment: ну допустим, есть у вас такой скрипт. вот вы его запустили. изменений на дисках нет, скрипт ничего и не выводит. и тут вдруг какой-нибудь процесс бац и создаёт огромный файл! оу, именно про это вы и хотите знать. и скрипт вам про это даже напишет. но вы в этот момент не смотрели на монитор, а взглянули только через минуту. и что вы видите? «нет никаких изменений». всё верно: за последние 7-10 секунд никаких изменений не было. и какой же тогда смысл в этом вашем скрипте?

Comment: Спасибо, команда watch, дала мне нужный результат